Solving a second order differential equation with parity symmetry
I am trying to reproduce the Figure 2 from this paper.

The code that I am using to solve the differential equation is given below:
lagrangian = 
  1/(6 \[Pi]) Sec[r]^3 Sqrt[4/(1 + Cos[r]^2 + Cos[r]^4) + (x1'[r])^2];

Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

eqofmotion = EulerEquations[lagrangian, x1[r], r] // Simplify;

NDSolve[{eqofmotion, x1[r] == -x1[-r], x1[0] == 0}, 
 x1[r], {r, 0, 2}]

which gives me an error. How do we get the Figure with the parity symmetry?
Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

I think that there is an error in the question: x1[r]==-x1[-r] is the property of odd functions / relations, but the plot above is not the plot of a odd relation. The plot looks like the plot of a even relation aka x1[r]==x1[-r].

@KevinDietrich you can check the linked paper. I have just restated what they have written in their paper.

If the potential is even the force, being the derivative of the potential, is odd.

@evanb should I try to break the NDSolve into two then? One for the positive side and one for the negative?

Sorry, I think I understand better.  Because the lagrangian respects parity you know the solutions have definite parity.  It seems you're looking for the odd solutions.
It may make sense to solve the eom on just the positive interval (also seems to be be what you're doing) and then construct the solution on the negative side via parity.

This problem can be solved in term of inverse function $r(x1)$ as follows
lagrangian = 
  1/(6 \[Pi]) Sec[r]^3 Sqrt[4/(1 + Cos[r]^2 + Cos[r]^4) + (x1'[r])^2];

Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

eqofmotion = 
 Last[EulerEquations[lagrangian, x1[r], r][[1]] // 
     Numerator] /. {x1'[r] -> 1/y'[x], x1''[r] -> -y''[x]/y'[x]^3} /. 
  r -> y[x]


eq = eqofmotion  y'[x]^3 // Simplify

R1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq == 0, y[0] == rc, y'[0] == 0}, 
  y, {x, -6, 6}, {rc}]

Visualization
Quiet@Plot[
  Table[If[Abs[R1[rc][x]] <= Pi/2, R1[rc][x], 
    Pi/2], {rc, {.001, .2, 1}}], {x, -5.9, 5.9}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x1", "r"}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}]



Thanks for the illuminating answer. I have one doubt. In the paper, they haven't given values of rc. How did you choose those specific values like .001, .2, 1 ?

@codebpr Formally we should solve equation R1[rc][L_q/2]=\pi/2. The corresponding code is FindRoot[R1[rc][#/2] == Pi/2 - 10^-3, {rc, .0001}, PrecisionGoal -> 4,     AccuracyGoal -> 3] & /@ {12, 3, 1}, and we have {{rc -> 0.000206338}, {rc -> 0.182432}, {rc -> 0.959632}}. But curve with first root is too wide, and we make it with rc=0.001.

Thank you for clarifying my doubt, and once again, many thanks for such an informative and useful answer.

@codebpr You are welcome!

I tried breaking the NDSolve into two after getting insights from @evanb's comment:
lagrangian = 
  1/(6 \[Pi]) Sec[r]^3 Sqrt[
    4/(1 + Cos[r]^2 + Cos[r]^4) + (x1'[r])^2];
Needs["VariationalMethods`"];
eqofmotion = EulerEquations[lagrangian, x1[r], r] // Simplify;

sol1 = NDSolve[{eqofmotion, x1[0] == 0, x1[Pi/2] == 3}, 
  x1, {r, 0, Pi/2}]

sol2 = NDSolve[{eqofmotion, x1[0] == 0, x1[-Pi/2] == 3}, 
  x1, {r, 0, Pi/2}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x1[r] /. sol1], Evaluate[x1[r] /. sol2]}, {r, 0, Pi/2},
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotLabel -> "Static String Profile", 
 FrameLabel -> {"r (Radial Coordinate)", "x1 (Spatial Profile)"}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Blue]

And this gives me the required plot (though rotated):

I would still be grateful to others if they had better solutions to the original problem. Thanks in advance!

The problem you try to solve is not same as in the paper linked. Please, note, they define equation on $r_c\le r\le\pi/2$, with $x1(r_c)=0, x1(\pi/2)=\pm L_q/2$.

@AlexTrounev I understood my mistake that's why I posted a new question here regarding the same. It would be very kind of you if you can provide some help :)

It could be better to give answer here, since we used transformation of eqofmotion.
